# Hibernate mapping with dynamic query

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have a dynamic query that is being generated in base of some data passed to a function. For this reason, I don't actually know how many columns I will have in my result. (The query is a pivot of Oracle 11G).
I know that all the generated columns will be numeric items, there's a fixed column that will be always a string.
How can i get a `map<String, List<Double>>` from hibernate mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Just create select in HQL and get list of map.

As a example:

```
select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n ) from Cat cat
```

Using native query tutorial:
http://www.flexjunk.com/2008/03/07/native-sql-in-hibernate/

Comment: in HQL I think I can't use the pivot function, any idea on how to use this in SQL, mapped in an hibernate mapping xml file?

Comment: Use tutorial from second link :)